VirtualBox can't operate in VMX mode
Recently, I tried to use VirtualBox and got this error,
VirtualBox can't operate in VMX root mode.
Please disable the KVM kernel extension, recompile your kernel and reboot.
(VERR_VMX_IN_VMX_ROOT_MODE).

I'm Running Ubuntu Noble Numbat; I upgraded to this version, so I've not always been running VirtualBox with it. Nevertheless, the last time I used VirtualBox successfully was with Noble Numbat. I am vaguely aware of what KVM is, but I definitely would rather not recompile the kernel if that is avoidable.
I do use docker, and on occasion multipass, I really don't want to create problems with them by disabling KVM. if there is a way to use VirtualBox with KVM then that would be greatly appreciated, otherwise I'm open to recompiling the linux kernel (if you answer with that please give me a link to or instruction on how to recompile it).
The host machine is ... really old it's a late 2012 macbook pro, the 4-cores-that-look-like-8 version. Some specs that are relevant.

Cores: 4 cores, but it looks like 8 because each core can run 2 processes (I think).
Processor: 8 x Intel Core i7-3720QM CPU @ 2.60GHz
Graphics Processor: NVE7 (I don't have very good GPU drivers, but I don't think that would be the problem)
Kernel Version: 6.5.0-9-generic (64-bit)
Hard drive is external (internal one is broken)
Virtualbox version: 7.0.18r162988

Sometimes Ubuntu will leave old versions of the kernel sitting around that you can choose to use while booting up. I looked into if I could do this and found that Ubuntu didn't leave one this time. I'd love to say that I had done more but I'm pretty clueless about this, and unfortunately I don't really know
 
VirtualBox error picture

Hi, can you tell us detail about the host of the virtualbox, and the step you try to do to fix it ?

Okay, I've added the information.

And old host, can you check the bios and see if their is an option for virtualization, if the option it's turned off, turn it on and try again

Gotta say, I'm a little confused. Older versions of VirtualBox and KVM have coexisted just fine on my home server. I wonder if anything changed.

@Maslite Old macs don't have a bios, the best I've got is the ability to chose which medium I boot off of and if I want to do an emergency boot from the internet. other than that I've got nothing.

Two possible solution here:
From this Ubuntu FAQ, Kernel and VBox can have conflitch you must apply the different command in order to fix it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/FAQ
From the article


Make sure you've completely shut down and powered off all your KVM virtual machines (using virt-manager or otherwise).




Unload all of its modules:



$ sudo invoke-rc.d kvm stop
In Karmic use


$ sudo invoke-rc.d qemu-kvm stop
instead.


In Lucid and later, use


$ sudo service qemu-kvm stop

From this reddit post : https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/comments/rjidvs/why_wont_it_let_me_disable_kvm_i_dont_want_kvm/
One user recommend to check the bios and make sure the virtualization option is disabled.
Now you have an old machine maybe the processor is too old for virtualization.

Thanks! that was so weird, I'm glad I've got virtualbox back, and didn't have to recompile anything or even reboot!

Anytime good sir :)
